# Quick way to identify observations that meets certain criteria in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

```
library('data.table')
set.seed(1)
A<-data.table(age = rnorm(10, mean = 10), V1= rnorm(10))
```

The situation is that I want to create a new column in the `data.table` A, that for each observation, it will look for any observation that has a age gap between 0.5 to 1 years, and use the value for `V1` of that observation as `V2` for the current observation. And if there are multiple observations that meet the criteria, just identify the observation that is closest to the 0.5 year gap.

I am wondering if there is a quick way to achieve that in data.table without using a `for` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible... and fun... but not so beautiful, neither readable:

```
CJ(A1=A$age,A2=A$age)[,.(A1, A2,d=abs(A1-A2))
                      ][d>=0.5 & d<=1
                        ][, .(d, dmin=min(d),A2), by="A1"
                          ][d==dmin
                            ][A, .(A1, A2,V2=i.V1,d), on=c(A2="age"), nomatch=0
                              ][A, .(age=A1, A2, V1, d, V2), on=c(A1="age")]

          age        A2          V1         d          V2
 1:  9.373546 10.183643  1.51178117 0.8100971  0.38984324
 2: 10.183643 10.738325  0.38984324 0.5546814  0.94383621
 3:  9.164371  9.694612 -0.62124058 0.5302402  0.59390132
 4: 11.595281 10.738325 -2.21469989 0.8569561  0.94383621
 5: 10.329508  9.694612  1.12493092 0.6348962  0.59390132
 6:  9.179532  9.694612 -0.04493361 0.5150800  0.59390132
 7: 10.487429  9.694612 -0.01619026 0.7928174  0.59390132
 8: 10.738325 10.183643  0.94383621 0.5546814  0.38984324
 9: 10.575781  9.694612  0.82122120 0.8811697  0.59390132
10:  9.694612  9.179532  0.59390132 0.5150800 -0.04493361
```

Comment: Hi HubertL, Thank you a lot for the answer! I wonder if it is possible to do this if the data is stack with different unique identifiers. So if there are two or more persons, is it possible to do this with a `by = id` ?

Comment: If you use '\n][' instead of '][\n' your editor may line up the columns cleanly for each row in the pipeline

Comment: you can do (much) faster using either rolling joins or non-equi joins, but it won't be any prettier

Comment: You're welcome @YDao. I dont' quite understand what you mean with `by=id`. It is better to ask a new question with new requirement (please include the expected result)